# Error installing Android app with Spotify SDK, [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]

Tags: android

I'm trying to follow the [tutorial for using the Spotify Beta SDK](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/tutorial/) and keep getting this error whenever I try to install the app onto the (Nexus 6) emulator. It's [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]. I'm using the same code as in in tutorial, I found something about compiling for ARM vs. Intel but am not sure what it means/how to use that information.
Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Spotify SDK includes native library for ARM architecture and ARM architecture only.

Since INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS is caused by the device the APK being installed not supported by the APK (i.e. the APK doesn't include native library for the device's CPU architecture), my guess is that you are trying to run it on an x86 emulator, which Spotify SDK doesn't support.

Try creating an ARM emulator and it should work.

**Edit:** To create an emulator configuration for ARM do the following:

1. Click "AVD Manager" -> "Create Virtual Device"
2. Select "Nexus 6" -> "Next"
3. Select one with *armeabi-v7a* ABI like below:

[image]

Comment: I'm using the built-in Android emulators, was under the impression that they were all ARM. How can I create an ARM emulator specifically? Also thanks!

Comment: @aRk edited answer to answer your comment question, you can also see that there are quite a number of ABIs listed: armeabi-v7a / x86_64 / x86 / mips, though most real devices will be armeabi-v7a based with some x86/x86_64 here and there