# Installing Facebook apk on Android Emulator

Tags: android, facebook, android-emulator

Has anyone managed to do this?!

I've tried various combinations of sdk/apk from this site with no luck.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads

When I use this SDK...

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.0'
}
```

... it *only* seems to work with targetSdkVersion "L". So fine. I run that emulator in x86 and use adb to install

```
./sdk/platform-tools/adb install Facebook-25.0.0.19.30.apk
```

I get "INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS". On ARM, I have not managed to get the emulator to actually start. It's been "Preparing Recommendations" for over 30 minutes now.

With a lower Facebook sdk version (com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.21.1), I am able to run the emulator with a targetSdkVersion of 19, and install the Facebook.apk (Facebook APK 22.0)

Unfortunately, when I open the Facebook app, I get the message that

```
"This version of android is no longer supported. please upgrade your device and try again"
```

I must be doing something wrong. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24572239/2823516)

> INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS is when you are trying to install an
>   app that has native libraries and it doesn't have a native library for
>   your cpu architecture. For example if you compiled an app for armv7
>   and are trying to install it on an emulator that uses the Intel
>   architecture instead it will not work.

Also, you can implement a solution on the emulator as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27596689/2823516).

And, for the second error I think it's pretty clear: Facebook won't let you use that app because they don't support it anymore.

Comment: Right. So it seems the only emulator supported by facebook's apk is the "L" sdk version on ARM. Which is pretty strange. I can't imagine that the facebook apk works only on the android TV emulator and not phone emulator. So I'm sure there's something else wrong.

Comment: Android L doesn't exist anymore. It's called Lollipop, is the API 21 and is not Android TV. Is the latest version of Android for smartphones and tablets.

Answer (score 2):

With the newer Facebook SDKs, I couldn't find the Facebook APK file bundled with the [Downloads - Facebook Android SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads/).

To install facebook on an emulator:

- I installed the Google Play Intel Atom Image from the SDK Manager.

[image]

- Created an AVD with the Google Play Intel Atom Image

[image]

- Now you can install Facebook from the Play Store (after sign in)

[image]

Now you can use Facebook to test Native login, etc,.