# Facebook SDK (android) login button not responding

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.x

I've created an app that uses the Facebook SDK for logging in, using the accepted code in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30230718/4529864.

It works great when deployed to my android phone (Nexus 4 with Lollipop, which has the facebook app installed).

When I use the emulator (Nexus 4 with Lollipop, which doesn't have the facebook app), it launches a webview login screen (https://i.stack.imgur.com/R69G0m.png). However, the 'Log In' button is unresponsive. No messages appear in the logs when I click the button. It just doesn't do anything!

Has anyone seen this before? Any suggestions on how to debug?

Comment: We have exactly the same problem. Tested on Lenovo, Samsung and other devices with Android 4 and 5. Have you found a solution?

Comment: No solution yet. I'm think this is just an issue with the emulator (can't reproduce on a real device - can you?). Plus I suspect most users of my app will have the Facebook app installed.

Comment: Yes, we can. It happens for example on Lenovo A8 (4.4.2). No solution found yet and it is stopping us in publishing the app :/ (With FB app installed it works.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the Facebook app in the emulator ? that is why it is opening webview.

Make sure you have internet connectivity enabled in your android app manifest. That should fix your issue.

Comment: Yes, I have internet connectivity. How do I install Facebook on the emulator? This post doesn't help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28891844/installing-facebook-apk-on-android-emulator.

Comment: This still doesn't explain why the webview login is not working.